# Flutter rejected from apple review

Tags: ios, flutter

I submitted my app for review to apple but they rejected it with the below reason

Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness

We discovered one or more bugs in your app. Please review the details below and complete the next steps.

Specifically, your app does not load any content on the OnCall, All Pharmacies or Map screen.

Review device details:

- Device type: iPhone and iPad
- OS version: iOS 16.5

Next Steps

Please run your app on a device to reproduce the issues, then revise and submit your app for review. If at first you're unable to reproduce the issue, try the following:

- For new apps, uninstall all previous versions of your app from a device, then install and follow the steps to reproduce.
- For app updates, install the new version as an update to the previous version, then follow the steps to reproduce.

I have tested the app and its working fine at simulator, real device, TestFlight

Anyone who have the same problem and how you solve it?

Comment: At least one of those functions sounds like it may rely on the users location. Does your app work correctly if the user declines to provide their location? If they are located in California? If they have no network connection? If they have a pure ipv6 connection. Have you deleted your app from your device before installing the testflight build?   Have you asked someone else to try a TestFlight build?

Comment: Does you code handle "unhappy paths" and errors?  Use the network link conditioner in the developer menu on iPhone to simulate bad/slow networks

Comment: finally it was the package location of flutter, I changed it to geolocator and pass!